# How to match start and end of input with std::regex on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++

From what I understand, C++ regex symbol `^` should match only the beginning of input and `$` should match only the end of input. This can be changed to match begin and end of every line with the `std::regex::multiline` flag.
Unfortunately Visual Studio 2017 fails to conform to this behavior:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <exception>

int main()
{
    std::string test = "\n \n\t \nThe previous three line should be removed.\n    \nThe previous line shouldn't be removed, "
        "but the next two should be:\n\t\t\t\n  ";

    std::string out;
    try {
        std::regex re(R"(^\s*\n|\n\s*$)");
        out = std::regex_replace(test, re, "");
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << out << std::endl;
}
```

This will keep the empty line between the two text lines on GCC, but it will be removed under MSVC. Any way to fix this behavior, or even better a portable solution? Is it a bug or intended behavior? Is it compliant to the standard?

Comment: `$(?![\s\S])` can be used to match end of string. Without a lookbehind support it is impossible to emulate `\A` anchor though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got hung up on this issue as well. It turns out that this non-standard behavior is expected from Visual Studio 2017 for historical reasons, but they would like to change it in the future.

Here's a link with more info (pasted below for posterity): https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/multiline-c/268592

> We marked this as an LWG issue resolution rather than a feature in our
> C++17 support tables; this is ABI breaking for us to implement so it
> won't happen until the regex engine is overhauled in an ABI breaking
> release.
>
> MSVC++'s engine always has "multiline" behavior, following
> Boost::Regex' design (from which the TR1 regex proposal was derived)
> which was multiline by default and had a singleline option. For some
> reason though, the singleline switch from Boost.Regex wasn't
> standardized.
>
> The other standard libraries assumed ECMAScript/browsers' defaults,
> and so only had single line mode.
>
> Through discussion in LWG it was decided that because the standard
> normatively references ECMAScript, and the default there is single
> line, that std::regex should not be like Boost.Regex here, MSVC++
> would need to change its engine to be singleline by default, and all
> the standard libraries would add a multiline switch.
>
> Unfortunately the representation our regex engine uses doesn't allow
> easy incorporation of a singleline flag to implement singleline
> support, and even if it did, changing that default would be likely to
> introduce subtle changes in behavior to existing programs that just
> recompile with a compiler update.
>
> As a workaround for now, we continue to recommend Boost.Regex; it not
> only has more consistent behavior in this area, its performance
> crushes that of all 3 major standard library implementations at
> present (
> https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/background/performance.html
> )
>
> Can't wait for the ABI break in the sky where we can fix this!
>
> Billy O'Neal
>
> Visual C++ Libraries